# Filtering records from large database in larave5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

I am having 1 million records in database with relationships. I need to add filter through range slider.
in my DB having no.of companies data, every company has employees count.
now, i want to filter employees between 10 to 10,000. i am using below query it's takes large amount of time(20mins) to filter.
How can i solve this

```
$company_data =Company::whereBetween('employees',[10,10000])->with('country','industry','company_financial')->skip($request->start)->take($request->length)->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happen if you remove `with()`??

Comment: i am retrieving data from different tables using relationships

Comment: i just want to know if there any changes if you remove with

Comment: Yes, using "with" getting company related to which country, industry and financial details. if i remove "with" i didn't get full details about company.

Comment: Show us the resulting SQL, please.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the data in chunks by using laravel pagination?

Append this to the end of your eloquent query:

```
->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: i am using yajra laravel-datatables, So, i wouldn't use paginate

Comment: seems like you can.. have a look at this: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1296